# i can not write the letters "f and g" using keyboard

Tags: keyboard

i am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and can not write the letters "f,g".this type of problem is not known for me.is this for language update properly not done during installation?

Comment: What keyboard layout & language are you using? If the keys don't work it is likely a hardware failure not software.

Comment: i'm using enlish (US). keys are working. i'm writing bengali with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it say En, instead of Da here?

[image]

If not, you need to click on it and change keyboard to English (US). Check online to see if Bengali is compatible on US English keyboards.